# CSS - Can't change the text color in a defined class

Tags: css

I have defined a class inside an ul:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"> <a ............></li>
    <li> <a ...........></li>
</ul>
```

And in CSS I am trying to make the item with class `current` a certain color and bolder, while keeping the rest of the list in the default color of  and in normal weight.

So in CSS I wrote:

```
body {
   color: #3d3d3d;
   font-weight: normal;
}

li.current {
   color: #7a78dd;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

So my problem is, when I wrote these, bold is working for the `current` class, but not the color. It was still in the color of body.

What are some of the things I should try to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the fact that the `li` contains an `<a>` tag.

The reason for this is that `<a>` tags need to have their properties defined explicitly.

Define the color like so:

```
li.current a {
   color: #7a78dd;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

I've know *some people* to override `<a>` tags in their custom `reset.css` like shown below (to take the color of their parent elements), but that is personal preference.

```
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have given color on `li` to still `a` tag taking default `color: -webkit-link;` so you couldn't see color on `a`. What you can do you can give css to `a` tag itself, like following:

```
li.current a {
   color: #7a78dd;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**See it in Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/tt1tgopL/)

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this because you add color on `li` not on `li`'s `a`-

```
li.current a{
   color: #7a78dd;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
li.current a {
color: #7a78dd !important;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also include your anchor tag in your css

```css
body {
   color: #3d3d3d;
   font-weight: normal;
}

li.current a {
   color: #468847;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current"> <a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">two</a></li>
</ul>
```